# error: ‘parent_window’ undeclared

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I've got problem with compiling program in C. I want to run simply file chooser with this code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *dialog;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",parent_window,action,_("_Cancel"),GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,_("_Open"),GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,NULL);                   

 if (gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
  {
    char *filename;
    GtkFileChooser *chooser = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (dialog);
    filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (chooser);
    open_file (filename);
    g_free (filename);
  }

  gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

I compile that by using that command:

```
gcc -o s5 s5.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

And I got that errors:

```
s5.c:10:39: error: ‘parent_window’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                                       parent_window,
                                       ^
s5.c:10:39: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
s5.c:11:39: error: ‘action’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                                       action,
                                       ^
s5.c:16:39: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
                                       NULL);
                                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:99:0,
                 from s5.c:1:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkfilechooserdialog.h:63:12: note: expected ‘const gchar *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 GtkWidget *gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new              (const gchar          *title,
            ^
```

I've tried to do the same with GTK+ 2 and also got the same errors ;/

Comment: Where is `parent_window` declared in your code sample?

Comment: For that matter, where is `action` declared?

Comment: (There are rhetorical, btw... I'm just re-telling you what the compiler told you already.) The answer to both of these questions is that neither variable is declared.. which is why the compiler is complaining, and why you're seeing some of these errors.

Comment: Fixed problem.
There was problem that program wanted 2 methods.

Comment: Can you post your fixed code as a new answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these people who want to run file selection from gtk+ example this is answer:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[]){

    //dialog variable
    GtkWidget *dialog;    

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    //Define dialog
    dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",NULL,GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,GTK_STOCK_OPEN,GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,NULL);

    //If file was choosen                 
    if (gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT){
        char *filename;
        filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (dialog));   
        printf("Selected file: %s\n", filename);
    } else {
        gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
        return 0;
    }


    gtk_main();  
}
```

To compile that you need to use that command:

```
gcc -o s6 s6.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is some variables are undeclared; you must have copied and pasted the code from some example and forgot to define them. To make a very simple GTK dialog example, try this:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *dialog;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Open File",
            NULL, GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
            "_Cancel", GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
            "_Open", GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
            NULL);

    if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT) {
        char *filename;
        GtkFileChooser *chooser = GTK_FILE_CHOOSER(dialog);
        filename = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename(chooser);
        g_message("File selected: %s", filename);
        g_free(filename);
    }

    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

and compile with what you suggested:

```
gcc -o s5 s5.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```